# Need query for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

`Users`:

```
UserID(int)   Username   Password   PagesID(varchar(50))
---------------------------------------------------------
  1            admin       123       1,2,3,4
  2             user       456       1,3
```

`Pages`:

```
PageID(int)       PageURL         PageTitle
---------------------------------------------
   1           article.aspx        Articles
   2            News.aspx           News
   3           reports.aspx         Reports
   4            Users.aspx          Users
```

I want to get `user.`, `pageURL` and `PageTitle` from `pages` and `Users` tables.

I need query same it + user info:
(this query returns column without rows.)

```
select p.PageURL 
from Pages p
where CONVERT(Varchar(50), p.PageID) in (select u.PagesID 
                                         from Users u
                                         where u.ID = 1)
```

Comment: **Don't** store multiple values in the same column, instead make a new link table like `usersPages` with a foreign keys references to users and pages tables. Also **don't** store passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a very poor data structure.  SQL has a great method for storing lists of things -- it is called a table, not a string.  You should have a junction table, with one row per user and per article.  So, in `UserPages`, there would be four rows for the first user.

Sometimes, we are stuck with data that we have no ability to change.  If that is the case, you can do what you want, but it is inefficient.  Here is one way:

```
select u.UserId, p.*
from users u join
     pages p
     on ',' + u.PagesId + ',' like '%,' + cast(p.pageId as varchar(255)) + ',%';
```

Comment: thanks for answering, i have created another table 'users_pages' , but i thought that maybe this way is been better than using junction. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @mortazavi The "easy" way is usually a good indication of the wrong way as well. You're using an anti-pattern called *multi-valued attributes* (http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=hobbies.php) which violates the first normal form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). For the sake of people you work with and your clients / users **please** don't perpetuate horrible database design.

Comment: a very cool way of avoiding split function for a situations like this :)

Comment: @M.Ali But you have `%` on both sides of the `LIKE` operator which (as far as I know) means that the query can't benefit from an index on the column being queried. Just another reason that although this is not a bad answer it is decidedly a bad design.

Comment: @Yuck . . . Hence the comment "but it is inefficient".